# error array convert to string error laravel 8

Tags: arrays, laravel-8

I want to input select option, if the select option no option, show the input text with same name select or input

```
<div class="mt-2">
                                <label for="driver_id" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Nama Driver</label>
                                <div class="mt-1 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <select id="driver_id" name="nama_driver[]" class="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                                        <option value="">Pilih Nama Driver</option>
                                        @foreach ($drivers as $item)
                                            <option value="{{ $item->nama_driver }}">{{ $item->nama_driver }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <option value="manual">Input Manual</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" id="manual_driver" name="nama_driver[]" class="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Driver" style="display: none;">
                                    @error('nama_driver')
                                    <div class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

```
$data = $this->validate($request, $this->rules());
        $input = $request->all();

        if ($gambar = $request->file('gambar')) {
            $destinationPath = 'foto-armada/spk';
            $fotoGambar = date('YmdHis') . "." . $gambar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $gambar->move($destinationPath, $fotoGambar);
            $input['gambar'] = "$fotoGambar";
        } else {
            unset($input['gambar']);
        }
        foreach($request->input('nama_driver') as $nama_driver)
        {
          $input->assign($nama_driver);
        }
        $orderVendor = OrderVendor::create($input);
```

Error convert array to string

Comment: look up the entire error in your laravel.log. then copy/paste the entire stacktrace of that error in your original question